# Merge/synonymize [post-processing] and [postprocessing]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Please merge [post-processing](/questions/tagged/post-processing) and [postprocessing](/questions/tagged/postprocessing) and create a synonym as they seem to cover same subject.

Even if those can be manually retagged, it doesn't guarantee that there will be new entries with that tag, and I don't see anybody using them for different things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[postprocessing](/questions/tagged/postprocessing) has been merged into [post-processing](/questions/tagged/post-processing). A synonym here really isn't necessary because:

1. The tag is used by very few questions
2. A new tag creation rule was put into place that you can't create tags that are only different from another tag due to the addition/subtraction of a hyphen. Searching for the tag `postprocessing` already brings up the tag `post-processing` in the tag suggestion results. Adding the synonym serves absolutely no purpose whatsoever.